# Increasing <div> height when there is overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` that is set to a certain height. Is there a CSS property that allows the height to be increased when there is overflow?

Comment: Just increase what you have it set at now but, without seeing the markup, we can only guess at the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set **min-height** instead of **height**, but this is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: If you need support for IE6 you can use height property for it, it behaves same s min-height does in other more modern browsers.

Comment: By 'older browsers' he means IE. That's the only browser that did not support it till IE8.

Comment: @Pieter, both 'height' and 'min-height' are standard CSS.